# Jasmine, turn off default reporter

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I have Jasmine with custom reporter

```
var myReporter = {
  jasmineStarted: function(suiteInfo) {

    console.log('Running suite with ' + suiteInfo.totalSpecsDefined);
  },

  suiteStarted: function(result) {

    console.log('Suite started: ' + result.description + ' whose full description is: ' + result.fullName);
  },

  specStarted: function(result) {

    console.log('Spec started: ' + result.description + ' whose full description is: ' + result.fullName);
  },

  specDone: function(result) {

    console.log('Spec: ' + result.description + ' was ' + result.status);
    for(var i = 0; i < result.failedExpectations.length; i++) {


      console.log('Failure: ' + result.failedExpectations[i].message);
      console.log(result.failedExpectations[i].stack);
    }
  },

  suiteDone: function(result) {

    console.log('Suite: ' + result.description + ' was ' + result.status);
    for(var i = 0; i < result.failedExpectations.length; i++) {

      console.log('AfterAll ' + result.failedExpectations[i].message);
      console.log(result.failedExpectations[i].stack);
    }
  },
  jasmineDone: function() {
    console.log('Finished suite');
  }
};

jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(myReporter);

describe('Top Level suite', function() {
  it('spec', function() {
    expect(1).toBe(1);
  });

  describe('Nested suite', function() {
    it('nested spec', function() {
      expect(true).toBe(true);
    });
  });
});
```

live: http://jsfiddle.net/wLnmbh88/

Now results show on html and console but I need turn off this in html. How can I show test results only in console? 
Code example is from jasmine documentation.

Answer (score 9):

No need to remove `jasmine-html.js` and fiddle with a custom `boot.js`. Just remove any reporters before adding your reporter of choice:

```
var jasmineReporters = require('jasmine-reporters');
jasmine.getEnv().clearReporters();
jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasmineReporters.TapReporter());
```

Comment: hmm it still is in my setup and a quick search doesn't show a change, so maybe `jasmine-reporters` wasn't added unlike in the asker's code - I'm adding a line to show this, above the previous two lines

Comment: @doyexar did this answer your question?

Comment: Works for me as well. Should be marked as correct answer.

Answer (score -1):

Default HTML reporter is added in the files `jasmine-html.js` and `boot.js` [in your JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wLnmbh88/).

`jasmine-html.js` ([source](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/blob/v2.3.4/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine-html.js)) - is actually a reporter itself, implemented via Jasmine reporter API;
`boot.js` ([source](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/blob/v2.3.4/lib/jasmine-core/boot.js)) - a file, which configures environment for Jasmine and executes it. Also, it activates default HTML reporter, because both of these files are considered Jasmine's core, so by including them all you would have a basic Jasmine installation.

In your case you want to implement a custom reporter + you want to get rid of default HTML reporter, so you should just remove `jasmine-html.js` and replace `boot.js` with custom one. There is a page in Jasmine docs about [configuring custom boot](http://jasmine.github.io/2.3/custom_boot.html) and [annotated source](http://jasmine.github.io/2.3/boot.html) for it.

Basic custom boot script for Jasmine 2.x without any reporters enabled should look kinda like this:

```
(function() {

  window.jasmine = jasmineRequire.core(jasmineRequire);

  var env = jasmine.getEnv();
  var jasmineInterface = jasmineRequire.interface(jasmine, env);

  extend(window, jasmineInterface);

  window.setTimeout = window.setTimeout;
  window.setInterval = window.setInterval;
  window.clearTimeout = window.clearTimeout;
  window.clearInterval = window.clearInterval;

  var currentWindowOnload = window.onload;

  window.onload = function() {
    if (currentWindowOnload) {
      currentWindowOnload();
    }
    env.execute();
  };

  function extend(destination, source) {
    for (var property in source) destination[property] = source[property];
    return destination;
  }

}());
```

Make sure, that you include this boot script after `jasmine.js`.

After you have your boot set up, you can register your reporter as usual:

```
jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(myReporter);
```

or even better - add it in the boot script.

Check JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wLnmbh88/2/